# How to conclude that all group means are different?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, tukey-hsd-test

Suppose I have groups $G_1$ to $G_n$ with sample means of the variable of interest $m_1$ to $m_n$ respectively and sample variances $s_1^2$ to $s_n^2$.

What tests can I perform to conclude that the respective population means $\mu_i\neq \mu_j$ whenever $i \neq  j$?

Preferably without assuming equal variances.

Comment: Looks like a job for Tukey(HSD) test.

Comment: What does Tukey do?

Comment: It's an expansion of univariate t-tests for multiple comparisons, read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test. Of course, you need standard errors of all the means as well, otherwise there is no testing to be done in any form.

Comment: In the sentence `Suppose I have groups G_1 to G_n with population means`, did you mean sample means? As in coming from a sample from a population? Do you have this sample data?

Comment: Edited to clarify

Comment: "conclude that *all* group means are different" ... Would $\mu_i=\mu_j$ for any pair $i \neq j$ (and all other $\mu_k $ still different) already contradict with your hypothesis?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Yes

Comment: Maybe a dup:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94444/three-binomial-random-variables-test-null-that-no-two-have-equal-mean/384873#384873

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Yes, strictly no pair of means are equal

Comment: It seems like you whish some sort of hypothesis test. How do you want to tackle the type I and type II errors? Compute some p-value, use some error rate or use some Bayesian method?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings My initial through it to use the null hypothesis $\mu_i=\mu_j$ for some pair. Is this a sensible hypothesis? - I'm new to this statistics thing

Comment: You mean you test $H_0:\mu_i = \mu_j$ and then do this a number of times for some selection of pairs? That might work but how do you wish to express it? That is what I ask in the question in my previous comment. (e.g. I imagine a p-value might not be straightforward due to multiple comparisons)

Comment: You reply faster than I can revise my comments! I guess that is the crutch of the problem. The Tukey test has some method for dealing with family wise error - something that I don't fully understand and I'm not sure if it is appropriate for this problem.

Comment: I will of course try to do some of my own research as well as asking here

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options, which all include testing all group pair means:

1. Tukey HSD test, this is a single-step multiple comparison procedure and statistical test. It compares all possible pairs of means, and is based on a studentized range distribution (q) (this distribution is similar to the distribution of t from the t-test). However, the Tukey test has an assumption of `equal within-group variance across the groups associated with each mean in the test (homogeneity of variance)`.
2. A generalization of the Tukey test, the Tukey WSD post-hoc test of means for unequal variances and unequal sample sizes.
3. Post-hoc Kruskal-Dunn test which is a non-parametric version and makes no assumptions about variances.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94444/three-binomial-random-variables-test-null-that-no-two-have-equal-mean/384873#384873

Comment: I'm apprehensive about using the Tukey HSD statistics because the test is designed (according to the wikipedia) for the null hypothesis that  all means being compared are from the same population (i.e. μ1 = μ2 = μ3 = ... = μk). Whereas I am interested in testing the null hypothesis that any pair have equal mean.

Comment: My understanding however  is that the Tukey procedure produces a significance value for every pair of groups - what I don't understand is whether or not the adjustment to these significance values is still appropriate for my hyphothesis? - should i simply require that all of these significance values falls below the desired threshold?

Comment: @Dilitante Yes, Tukey assumes normal distribution within each group, this may or may not be a reasonable assumption in your case. If it's not, you can use one of the other two options which make no such assumptions. And yes, it will produce a p-value for each group pair and yes, you do have to adjust them since these are multiple tests. Tukey HSD, however, does not require p-value adjustment as it does so internally already, and I don't think Tukey WSD requires either. The Kruskal-Dunn test however requires adjustment.